# Multivariate nonlinear congruence equation with two different moduli

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to solve the following congruence equation system for x, y and z, where $n_1 < n_2$?

$a_1x + b_1xy  \mod n_1 = c_1z \mod n_2$

$a_2x + b_2xy \mod n_1 = c_2z \mod n_2$

$a_3x + b_3xy \mod n_1 = c_3z \mod n_2$

If three equations are not enough, more consistent ones are available.

Here, "$a \mod n_1 = b \mod n_2$" means they equal as integers, i.e., $\mathbb{Z}(a \mod n_1) = \mathbb{Z}(b \mod n_2)$.

This question pops up when I tried to analyze some symmetric cipher.
The iterative affine cipher is defined as follows.

The plaintext is $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{n_1}$.

The key is $k=(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2)$, where $a_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{n_1}$, $b_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_{n_1}$, $a_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$ and $b_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_{n_2}$.

The encryption works as
$$c = \mathrm{Enc}_k(m) = a_2 (a_1(m+b_1) \mod n_1) + b_2 \mod n_2.$$
I was considering mounting CPA (chosen plaintext attack) against the cipher. The CPA is basically choosing different plaintexts $m_i$ then getting the ciphertexts $c_i$ under the same key $k$. After collecting enough plaintext-ciphertext pairs $(m_i, c_i)$, I tried to solve for the key $(a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2)$, which ends up with the equation system above.

Note that I was actually working on a variant of iterative affine cipher which leads exactly to the equation I asked. But the description is rather complicated, so I used the basic iterative affine cipher to motivate the need for solving such an equation.

Comment: I am trying to analyze some symmetric cipher (precisely, iterative affine cipher), which ends with solving such an equation system.

Comment: You might get more pertinent answers if you elaborate on that context in your question.